# How re-activate TensorFlow in Python with Docker, OS X

Tags: macos, docker, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to tensorflow and Docker but was successful three weeks ago at setting up a Jupyter notebook and running several tensorflow examples. The Mac updated and I can't find that notebook and when I start a new one I get:

> ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in () ----> 1 import tensorflow
>   as tf 2 hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!') 3 sess =
>   tf.Session() 4 print(sess.run(hello)) ModuleNotFoundError: No module
>   named 'tensorflow'

I used the same command that worked three weeks ago:

```sh
$ docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 -v ~/lewleib/deepcars-master:/notebooks tensorflow/tensorflow
```

Last week I discovered a Dockerfile Image command but I can't reproduce this now. It gave:

```sh
Container ID: 4906b4b55fb2
Image. tensorflow/tensorflow
Command /run_jupyter.sh-...
Created 3 weeks ago
Ports  6006/ycp, 0.0.0.0:8888 > 8888/tcp
```

Now when I do `docker ps` I get the headings but no information.
When I do `docker run hello-world` I get

> Hello from Docker!
>
> This message shows that your installation appears
>   to be working correctly.

How can I configure my docker image to work properly?
Many thanks.

### Lew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container which was being used previously has been lost. To make sure, run `docker ps -a`.

Most probably the image being used still exists. You can check that using `docker images`.

Now that you know what pieces exist and what do not, you need to refer the steps which you did initially to create container.

Comment: Thanks Ayushya
I found the tensorflow/tensorflow container still exists:

    
When I did the command below I got an error message. I opened a Jupyter notebook I got the message below.  Then I still get the no tensorflow message. 


         Notebook validation failed
    The save operation succeeded, but the notebook does not appear to be valid. The validation error was:
    Notebook validation failed: Additional properties are not allowed ('metadata' was unexpected):
Thanks for your help.  Lew